# Should JPA entities return a constant for the hashcode() implementation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

[This article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/)  suggests a JPA `equals` and `hashcode` implementation that returns `31` always for the `hashcode`.  Would this not become a problem when we try to add entitities to a HashMap or HashSet?

In other words if I try insert a two JPA entity instances of type Product like this:

```
//Load product1 and product2
Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();
products.add(product1);
products.add(product2);
```

Will the products `Set` now contain two products even though the `hashcode` for both of these products is the same?

### Update

Just referencing [this question on whether hashcode() speeds up collection lookups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46537166/is-hashcode-used-to-speed-up-object-lookups-in-collections/46537192#46537192).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely. See [Class HashMap documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). HashSet is backed by a HashMap, so this applies to HashSet too. See [Class HashSet documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

To the second question, no. HashMap uses equality to decide whether an entity is equal. It will just be terribly inefficient since the map will degenerate to a linked list.