# Is hashcode used to speed up object lookups in collections?

Tags: java, jpa

IIUC it two different objects of the same type can be stored in a HashSet even though both objects return the same value when `hashCode()` is called.  For example according to [this article](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/04/the-3-things-you-should-know-about-hashcode/) "Aa" and "BB" return the same `hashcode` (2112), but obviously I can put both of these Strings in a `HashSet` and they will both be contained in the `Set` without "Aa" overwriting "BB".

So is the primary purpose then of `hashCode()` to make finding an instance in a Set, or collections in general, faster?  Also does this imply that if we return a constant for `hashCode()` that this will slow down the performance of a collections that store such objects (Within a [JPA context as suggested by this linked article for example](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
The basics of any bucket-based algorithm is that you want to have your elements spread evenly across N buckets, where `N << |all elements|`.
Having a constant hashCode would force all elements into the same bucket, reducing all find/contains operations to run using only underlying (the per-bucket) structure, that could be a List or somesuch.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Choosing_a_hash_function for generic explaination. Right now Java `HashSet` is just backed by `HashMap` (from Javadoc) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Sets).